# How does [NSLocale preferredLanguages] work?

Tags: ios, internationalization

[NSLocale preferredLanguages] returns an array of language codes as strings. The object at index 0 returns the current language setting for the device, but how is the rest of the list (if it's longer than length 1) determined?

Comment: I believe this is determined by the user in Settings. If they have a second language (etc) they're willing to use should their first language not be available, then you can fall back to the second choice, third choice etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured this out. [NSLocale preferredLanguages] is based on the list under Settings App --> General --> International --> Language. The default list can be viewed in the iOS Simulator by going to iOS Simulator --> Reset Contents and Settings and then going to the language list. If the user selects a new language, that language goes to the top of the list.

Comment: You make my day :) Very helpful!